# String and List manipulation in Java

Tags: java, string, list

So I want to make function to which I will pass a string say "sandals" and a list with indexes of the string say, [0, 1, 2], this functions needs to return a list which is [6,4,-1] because at index=0, there's "s", it'll traverse the whole string and and find out one more "s" is in 6th position, one more "a" is in 4th position and "n" doesn't occur again, so -1.

```
 import java.util.*;
  class list 
   {
     public void stringnList(String s, list l)
      {
              char arr[]=s.toCharArray();
              Arrays.sort(arr);
              List<int> q = new ArrayList<int>();
              for (int i:l)
              {
               for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++)
                {
                  if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                  q.append(j);
                  else
                  q.append(-1);
               }
        }
    for(int j:q)
    System.out.print(j+"\n");
   }
}
```

I know my code has errors, but I am having a hard time understanding and fixing them.

Comment: Why does the instance method take a parameter of it's own type? You class doesn't implement `Iterable`, so it cannot be used in enhanced for loop. Perhaps you should rename your class to something like `Test` (mixed case), and change the parameter to `List<Integer>`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. For example give examples of input data and the actual output.

Comment: Can you please fix the compile errors first? There are references to non-existent classes, calling list methods that don't exist, using primitives as type arguments... That makes it hard to see the problem.

Comment: [link](https://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/) here they're not using 'Iterable'

Comment: A) please learn about java naming conventions, class names go UpperCase B) on the other hand, never ever use names that already exist, so calling your class `List` wouldnt be good either (rather call it ListExample, or something alike). C) use names that *mean* something. `q` or `arr` mean nothing!

Comment: Beyond that, there is a ton of problems with your code. But you have to understand that this is not a tutor service were instructors get paid to work with you through your project. Just dropping some code with various compiler errors, without even telling us about them *within* the question is a **no go**. Seriously: re-visit the [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `indexOf`, though. This is why you need to be familiar with the standard library, so you don't end up reinventing the wheel.

```
public List<Integer> secondIndices(String s, List<Integer> indices) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(indices.size());
    for (int i : indices) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        result.add(s.indexOf(c, i + 1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

`indexOf(c, i + 1)` returns the first instance of `c` *after* position `i`. Use the method like this.

```
List<Integer> is = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
System.out.println(secondIndices("sandals", is));
```